# How to get JSON data from a Python POST request

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests

Whenever I try to get the answer of that POST request command, it returns only the first argument:

```
s = requests.post('https://martindarc59.typeform.com/app/form/result/token/AdHdvM/default')
print (s.text)
```

It should output this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqOQs.png)

However, I only get the token value and not the `landed_at`, I need both in my code to submit them at the end of my form.

Thank you !

Comment: How did you get the image? I'm also getting a single value rather than JSON when simply posting the link into my browser.

Comment: hello, when you enter the typeform the post request appears https://martindarc59.typeform.com/to/AdHdvM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the `"Accept": "application/json"` header, i.e.:

```
import requests

u = "https://martindarc59.typeform.com/app/form/result/token/AdHdvM/default"
j = requests.post(u, headers={"Accept": "application/json"}).json()
# {'token': '20903331626f396431746f397777693832713331626f39643136747572367978706434313339363936363463366336363533373434333536343134353337366237613339343233303664373236613737353935613431363436393336343833313335333833383332333733393336333333373633653233363637346132653432343938383963326537663165326535633262373837326336613437343539666638653932613131393266386236393635626131353838323739363337', 'landed_at': '1588279637'}
```

Comment: Your demo doesn't work. Can you give an example of this request via Postman?

Comment: The original question url used on this answer is 404, but the example is valid for other urls

Comment: I tried other urls, it seems that now this solution does not work! Please check it out.

Comment: Try my survey: https://uza3fcl1odf.typeform.com/to/tCsWUtMB then the url should be like this: https://uza3fcl1odf.typeform.com/app/form/result/token/tCsWUtMB/default It doesn't work!

Comment: Open a new question and post the link here as a comment. I'll try to help you then.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65890558/7460038